# Type hint for Tuple, if the number of arguments can be 2 or 3

Tags: python, tuples, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I would like to ask, how to write correctly type hints for ***args** variable in my situation.

I have this method:

```
def insert(self, *args) -> None:
```

***args** is in format **Union[Tuple[My_Class, str, ?], Iterable[Tuple[My_class, str, ?]]]**, where the third argument may be or doesn't have to be given. *It's marked with a question sign.*

I call this method with this statement:

```
form.insert(
            (first_field, "John", "Doe"),
            (date_field, "12251996"),
)
```

In summary ***args** can be Tuple, with 2 or 3 values inside, where the third argument is str, or is not given to this method
or it can be Iterable of Tuples, where the Tuple has the same values as in the previous case.

A tried these type hints, but it didn't give me what I need.

```
Union[Tuple[My_Class, str, Optional[str]], Iterable[Tuple[My_class, str, Optional[str]]]]
Union[Tuple[My_Class, str, ...], Iterable[Tuple[My_class, str, ...]]]
Union[Tuple[My_Class, str, Union[str, ...]], Iterable[Tuple[My_class, str, Union[str, ...]]]]
```

Does anyone have any idea, how to solve this, please?

Comment: Note that `Optional[a]` is short for `Union[a, None]`. It doesn't mean you can omit a value from the tuple, only that the value can be a value of type `a` or `None`.

Comment: `*args` is *always* an iterable, so `*args: a` implies that `args` has type `Tuple[a]`. I would just use `args: Union[Tuple[MyClass, str], Tuple[MyClass, str, str]]` and require the user to always pass an iterable of tuples, even if they only need to pass one tuple.

Comment: Thank you chepner. I'd rather do that way, but this part of code is in the module, that is already released, and it would be incompatible with previous version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add both versions to your `Union`

```
def insert(self, *args: Union[
    Tuple[X, str, str],
    Tuple[X, str],
    Iterable[Union[Tuple[X, str, str], Tuple[X, str]]]
]) -> None:
```

Though the size of that type alias suggests the method's doing too much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.9 or after, then instead of `Union` you can write bitwise or `|` character to visually separate types. This came from [PEP 604: Allow writing union types as X | Y](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) and you can read it for more details.

For your question, that would look like:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

def insert(
    self,
    *args: tuple[X, str, str] |
           tuple[X, str] |
           Iterable[tuple[X, str, str] |
                    tuple[X, str]]
) -> None:
```